# Rviz camera in ThirdPersonFollower view doesn't align correctly

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- ROS Kinetic

**Issues**

1. I notice that the camera in `rviz` in `ThirdPersonFollower` mode doesn't seem to align correctly. As can be seen in the figures below, I set focal point to `0; 0; 0`, yaw to `0`, and pitch to `0`. But the camera doesn't align correctly. Am I missing anything here?
2. Also, when I play the rosbag file, the camera pose seems to change from frame to frame, which I don't know what possible reasons could be. Does anybody have this kind of behavior?

What could be the possible reasons of this? Is this a known bug?

Here is some of the screenshots:

[image: image description]
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338525/rviz-camera-in-thirdpersonfollower-view-doesn%27t-align-correctly/) by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2019-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-11-25**:
Hi @ignite

1. It will always depends on the values you assigned to the `Fixed Frame` field in the Global options and the `Target Frame` field on the view options. Looking at the pictures you are visualizing in two different frames: `camera_init` and `aft_mapped`.
2. Dealing with TFs extracted from a rosbag is always a bit of a mess. I would recommend you to ensure you have a proper TF tree and then to record your rosbag with  `/tf /tf_static` and `/clock` topics to see if it a problem of the TF or the time at witch they are recorded.

**Comment by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on 2019-11-25**:
@Weasfas Thanks for your detailed comment. Please correct me if I am wrong. Regarding point #1, my understanding is that `Fixed Frame` is a frame that all objects in rviz is plotted "*with respect to*". So doesn't the [camera type](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide#The_different_camera_types) (and its settings) only depend on the `Target Frame`? Because according to [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide#Third_Person_Follower), it is said that the `ThirdPersonFollower` will maintain a constant viewing angle *towards the* `Target Frame`.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-11-26**:
As far as I know, the fixed frame tells rviz the relative coordinates of all plotted frames with respect to the `Fixed Frame` in the global setting. The thing is, the `Target Frame` in the view panel is more important because it is changing your local coordinates of the camera (E.g.: applying the coordinate offset). If you have a `Fixed Frame` as frame1 you can place the `Target Frame` with `<Fixed Frame>` but if you change it to another, the offset will be applied and you will be not aligned with the frame you want.

I performed some testing with a robot model in the `ThirdPersonFollower` view and as long as I use the proper coordinate frames the axis of the frame always plotted aligned. I am using your same set up: Ubuntu Xenial + Kinetic

**Comment by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on 2019-11-26**:
@Weasfas Thanks! I think I misunderstood the `ThirdPersonFollower` view typeThe document says that n `ThirdPersonFollower`, the camera will turn if the `Target Frame` yaws.

**Comment by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on 2019-11-26**:
@Weasfas I think I have found the solution from this [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/39118/binding-rviz-view-camera-position-and-orientation-to-tf-frame/). I need to set both `Fixed Frame` and `Target Frame` to the same frame.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-11-26**:
@ignite

Well, Glad you found a solution =)!

P.D. If you do not mind I will add here your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @ignite noted:

I think I have found the solution from this [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/39118/binding-rviz-view-camera-position-and-orientation-to-tf-frame/). I need to set both `Fixed Frame` and `Target Frame` to the same frame.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2019-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0